# Statistical Mechanics problem regarding the enthalpy and the expected value of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

So I have an assignment(relating to a chapter on Canonical Ensemble) here with
$H_E = \langle H\rangle$

where $H_E$ is the enthalpy,
and $\langle H\rangle$ is the average of the Hamiltonian, I think.

In the answer sheet, they begin by putting $$H_E = - \frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial \beta}$$

which I recognize as the expected value for energy $\langle E\rangle$.

So I assume $$H_E = \langle H\rangle =\langle E\rangle \;.$$

But I can't manage to justify this.

Comment: Can you clear what you are asking? are you asking how to derive the relation between enthalpy and the partition function $Z\;?$

Comment: Yeah basically.
Or well I know how to derive the expression above for the expectation value of the energy, that is <E>.
I just don't understand why it's the same expression for enthalpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that $H_e$ is actually enthalpy in this context? Because if as you say that $H_e$ is average of the hamiltonian as in $H_e = \langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle$, remembering that eigenstates of hamiltonian are states of well defined energy and their eigenvalues are energies then $\langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle$ is expectation value of energy and it only wakes sense that $ H_E=− {\frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial \beta }}$ i.e. this just says expectation value of energy of the system given by expectation value of Hamiltonian is equal to expectation value of energy of the system given by statistical mechanics. Because enthalpy as far a I know is usually defined as $H = \langle E\rangle + pV$ and if you are saying that you question suggests that $\textrm{enthalpy} = \langle E\rangle$ then either $p$ or $V = 0$ which in my opinion would be a very strange situation. So my  guess is that you could be misreading the question or the question may be not very clear what it is referring too.

Comment: Hi, Ilya! For quick reference on MathJax, do check this meta post: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020